# Android Splash activity not redirecting

Tags: android

I have created a splash activity for my app. I am trying to redirect from my Splash activity to the Starting Point activity using AndroidManifest.xml but its not working. The Splash class loads up, and then it doesn't redirect to the Starting Point. And it doesn't give any errors either.

So can you please help me figure it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.myapp.STARTINGPOINT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now I have also tried

```
<activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.myapp.STARTINGPOINT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So what can I do here. I am not getting redirected from Splash to my Starting Point.

Splash Code

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add your .java for your splash code? I feel like it could be a problem with the thread

Comment: Done. The splash is added above it is very simple one. I have created layout and am doing basically nothing.

Comment: Simple is good.  I have added an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your Splash.java

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally{
                Intent i = new Intent(Flash_Activity.this, StartingPoint.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

You are never calling anything to change the activity from your splash to the starting point.  This thread will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this easy way to redirect to acitvity

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
finish();
            }
        },2500);
```